# What is the number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements, containing a given element?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

All of the subsets can be of most $n$ elements. One term, $a_1$ of our set, has to be in our subset. From there we can choose wether we want $a_2$ to be in our subset of not, that gives $2$ choices. We can choose if $a_3$ is in our subset or not, again two choices....We can choose if $a_n$ is in our subset or not. By the multiplication principle we have:

$$(1)(2^{n-1})=2^{n-1}$$

Possible subsets.

Is my answer/approach correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: It's correct and it corresponds to the number of subsets of a set with $n-1$ elements.

Comment: As a variant, you might remark that your condition is the same as specifying a subset of a set with $n-1$ elements (your original $n$ less the chosen entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is perfectly correct. Here is a follow up :

**Questions :**

- What is the number of subsets in a set $E$ with n elements, containing a given $k\leq n$ elements?
- What is the number of subsets in a set $E$ with n
  elements,containing either $a_1$ or $a_2$ ($a_1$ and $a_2$ two given elements in $E$)?

Comment: Without loss of generality, we need $a_1$ to be in our subset. $a_2$ to be in our subset. ...$a_k$ to be in our subset. Then we have $2$ choices for ten remaining $n-k$ elements. That gives $(1)^k2^{n-k}=2^{n-k}$ possible subsets by the multiplication principle.    Is this correct and thanks for your follow up questions because it's helping me learn.

Comment: For the second question the number of subsets that contain $a_1$ is  $2^{n-1}$. The number of subsets that contain $a_2$ is  $2^{n-1}$. The number of subsets that contain $a_1$ and $a_2$ is $2^{n-2}$. Then the number of subsets that contain $a_1$ or $a_2$ is $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}-2^{n-2}$ by inclusion exclusion principle. But we are uninterested in a subset that contains both, so we must exclude them, given us a final answer of: $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}-2^{n-2}-2^{n-2}=2^n-2^{n-1}=2^{n-1}(2-1)=2^{n-1}$ correct?

Comment: Both your answers are perfectly correct, and you are good at analyzing and structuring the problem one of the required skills for problem solving. Now you should know that whenever you solve a problem then there is always a next harder one. And solved problems became a rule which will serve afterwards to solve other problems. Try also to work in checking your solutions yourself. So that you will have the ability to know if your answer is correct or not. Good luck.